# Python code for Solana PDAs

Tags: solana-program, python

I want to use PDAs in solana but there doesn’t seem to be any way of doing it with python. I looked to the Solana CLI library with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Find a program-derived address off-chain?

Answer (score 0):

PDAs can be used in Python through the Solana Py library. Solana Py is a Python library that provides a convenient way to interact with Solana's JSON RPC API and programmatic interfaces.

To use PDAs in Solana Py, you can use the Account.from_seed() method to create an account based on a seed.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use PDA than there is this new framework in python you can give a try to its called Seahorse-lang here is the [link](https://seahorse-lang.org/)